# Help understanding anti- symmetric and irreflexive property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Hi i have been working on a question is R anti-symmetric, irreflexive?
A ={1,2,3,4} R= {(1,3),(1,2),(3,2),(4,4)}

I worked out R is not anti- symmetric and is not irreflexive since (4,4) is related. The answer states i am wrong, can someone please help me understand this as other definitions have not help. Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not asymmetric, but it is anti-symmetric ... do you see why?

Comment: @Bram28: what on earth is an asymmetric binary relation? (Typo for "symmetric"?)

Comment: Your relation **is** antisymmetric: you never have $a\mathrel{R}b$ and $b\mathrel{R}a$.

Comment: it's not symmetric because (1,3) is in the relation but (3,1) is not in the relation. Although i am having trouble understanding the ant-symmetric property

Comment: @RobArthan Asymmetry is that when $(x,y)$ then not $(y,x)$ ... which is not what we have here because of $(4,4)$. I think the OP was thinking of asymmetry instead of anti-symmetry

Comment: @Bram28: your terminology is non-standard. The standard terminology is to say that a relation $R$ is antisymmetric if $a \mathrel{R}b$ implies that $\lnot b \mathrel{R} a$. There is no standard notion of asymmetric relation.

Comment: @RobArthan Huh. I must be looking at different websites than you. All the sites that come up when I google asymmetry say that if $aRb$ then $\neg bRa$, while anti-symmetry is:  if $aRb$ and $bRa$ then $a=b$. So, since in this problem we have $(4,4)$ it is not asymmetric, but since the only time where $aRb$ and $bRa$ is when $a=b=4$ it is anti-symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relation  $R$ is anti symmetric iff $$ (aRb \text { & } bRa) \implies a=b$$

This is what we have with our $R$.

The only case of $$ (aRb \text { & } bRa)$$ is $4R4$ and we have $4=4$ which makes our relation anti-symmetric.

Comment: does this mean that if it is true for at least one set in the relation the property is true?

Comment: Since this is the only case for which we have both aRb and bRa, we are done. In case that we have say, 3R5 and 5R3, we had to check 3=5 which makes it not anti symmetrics. Anti symmetric is like $\le$ if it goes both ways they have to equal.

Comment: Yes i get it now thank you

Comment: Thank you for attention and understanding.